# UIScrollView Delegate methods clashing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am using the following two UIScrollView delegate methods to call another method in my UIViewController:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // do something
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    // do something
}
```

I've tried various different ways of calling //do something but either end up with both not being called, or both delegate methods being called, calling //do something twice in certain situations. For example:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(![scrollView isDecelerating] && ![scrollView isDragging]){
        //do something
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{
    if(!decelerate){
        //do something
    }
}
```

So with the above if I scroll and let it slow to a stop, it calls scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:, but if I scroll and stop it with a tap it calls both scrollViewDidEndDragging: and scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:

I want it to call one or the other... is there something I can do with scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: and the scrollView object to stop this double method call?

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what exactly you want?

Comment: Can't you just try `scrollViewDidScroll` method instead if you dont have any complex things to do?

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll is too heavy. I've posted the solution below. I basically want a method to fire when scrolling stops either by decelerating naturally, or when the user stops a drag operation.

Answer (score 2):

The scroll view delegate does its job. You can not prevent it from happening. But with a simple logic you can achieve what you are trying to do.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    dragged = YES;
    // do something
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (!dragged) {

         // do something
    }

    dragged = NO;
}
```

Comment: BEWARE: scrollViewDidEndDecelerating may not be called after scrollViewDidEndDragging

Answer (score 2):

// very simple

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    if(!decelerate){
         // Do something 
    }

}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
       // Do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Close to [EmptyStack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909471/uiscrollview-delegate-methods-clashing/6909557#6909557)

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (!dragged) {
        //do something
    }

    dragged = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

    if(!decelerate){
        dragged = YES;
        //do something
    } else {
        dragged = NO;
    }
}
```